# How to calculate differences in a list of integers using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have the following array: `{1,2,3,4,6,7,8}` which is put in a `Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,6,7,8);`

How can I use in Java lambda expressions and Stream functions to calculate the difference between each element and the next (in this case `{1,1,1,2,1,1}`)?
This is not really a reduce operation as reduce transforms the entire list to 1 element; it also isn't a map operation as it requires two elements to calculate the difference and not just one.

Comment: Is the input indeed an array or do you already get an `IntStream`, with which you have to work? If you get the values as an array, [Ismail's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30697591/4216641) seems reasonable to me.

Comment: for the curious, this seems to *not* be feasible using `reduce`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350402

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can loop over the indices instead of the elements, e.g.

```
int s[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8};
IntStream differences = 
    IntStream.range(0, s.length - 1)
        .map(i -> s[i + 1] - s[i]);
```

Comment: OP requires `s` to be a stream (and I think using `toArray()` is not the way to go).

Comment: You create an Array, then a Stream, just use the stream to iterate over the Array. It looks redundant to me.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer seems to be accepted already, but had an idea so I post it anyway. You can make a `Collector` that collects it directly to another `Stream<Integer>`.

Then you can just write like:

```
s.collect(intDifferences()).forEach(d -> System.out.print(d + ","));
```

Here's an implementation I wrote:

```
public static Collector<Integer, List<Integer>, Stream<Integer>> intDifferences() {

    return new Collector<Integer, List<Integer>, Stream<Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Integer> accumulator() {
            return List::add;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return EnumSet.noneOf(Collector.Characteristics.class);
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> combiner() {
            return (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Function<List<Integer>, Stream<Integer>> finisher() {
            return list -> {
                List<Integer> differences = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    differences.add(list.get(i) - list.get(i - 1));
                }
                return differences.stream();
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Supplier<List<Integer>> supplier() {
            return ArrayList::new;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which has a [`pairMap`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#pairMap-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method specially for this case:

```
StreamEx<Integer> s = StreamEx.of(1,2,3,4,6,7,8);
s = s.pairMap((a, b) -> b-a);
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `StreamEx` class implements `Stream` and is fully compatible with it. The same thing works with primitive streams as well:

```
IntStreamEx s = IntStreamEx.of(1,2,3,4,6,7,8);
s = s.pairMap((a, b) -> b-a);
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `map()` if you allow the mapping function to have a side effect, i.e. you can store a reference to the previous object in the stream:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)
    .map(new Function<Integer, Optional<Integer>>() {
        Optional<Integer> previousValue = Optional.empty();
        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> apply(Integer current) {
            Optional<Integer> value = previousValue.map(previous -> current - previous);
            previousValue = Optional.of(current);
            return value;
        }
    })
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note, this implementation is not a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) so you have to be careful about how it is used. The example above works, because the function is instantiated every time (in particular, the `previousValue` will be reset for each usage). However, it will *not* work if the code is refactored so that the function is stored in a local variable, because the second time the function is used, the `previousValue` will not be empty. Consequently, this kind of implementation is often discouraged.

Comment: the function is instantiated only once. it's stateful after all

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] diff(int... input) {
    AtomicInteger aInt = new AtomicInteger();
    return IntStream.of(input).map(v -> v - aInt.getAndSet(v)).skip(1).toArray();
}
```

Not pure function since it change state of AtomicInteger