# Using Java 8 Stream Reduce to return List after performing operation on each element using previous elements values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I'm new to Streams and Reduce so I'm trying it out and have hit a problem:

I have a list of counters which have a start counter and end counter. The startcounter of an item is always the endcounter of the previous. I have a list of these counters `listItems` which I want to loop through efficiently, filter out inactive records and then reduce the list into a new List where all the StartCounters are set. I have the following code:

```
List<CounterChain> active = listItems.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getCounterStatus() == CounterStatus.ACTIVE)
                .reduce(new ArrayList<CounterChain>(), (a,b) -> { b.setStartCounter(a.getEndCounter()); return b; });
```

But it doesn't really work and I'm kind of stuck, can anyone give me a few suggestions to help me get this working? Or is there an equally efficient better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *Reduction* reduces all elements to a single value. Using a reduction function of the `(a,b) -> b` form will reduce all elements to the last one, so it’s not appropriate when you want to get a `List` containing all (matching) elements.

Besides that, you are performing a modification of the input value, which is violating the contract of that operation. Note further, that the function is required to be *associative*, i.e. it shouldn’t matter whether the stream will perform `f(f(e₁,e₂),e₃))` or `f(e₁,f(e₂,e₃))` when processing three subsequent stream elements with your reduction function.

Or, to put it in one line, you are not using the right tool for the job.

The cleanest solution is not to mix these unrelated operations:

```
List<CounterChain> active = listItems.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getCounterStatus() == CounterStatus.ACTIVE)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
for(int ix=1, num=active.size(); ix<num; ix++)
    active.get(ix).setStartCounter(active.get(ix-1).getEndCounter());
```

The second loop could also be implemented using `forEach`, but it would require an inner class due to its stateful nature:

```
active.forEach(new Consumer<CounterChain>() {
    CounterChain last;
    public void accept(CounterChain next) {
        if(last!=null) next.setStartCounter(last.getEndCounter());
        last = next;
    }
});
```

Or, using an index based stream:

```
IntStream.range(1, active.size())
    .forEach(ix -> active.get(ix).setStartCounter(active.get(ix-1).getEndCounter()));
```

But neither has much advantage over a plain `for` loop.

Comment: `reduces all elements to a single value` well that depends on the definition of "value". A List is also a value, an Object to be precise. Or what did you mean by that? - in Javascript for example, this "value" can also be an array and thus, transforming List A into List B can be done functionally easily. Striking this is not possible in Java. But disallowing modification of the input value makes sense.

Comment: @Blauhirn a “value” is whatever elements you might process and apply value semantics to. So you *can* reduce a stream of lists to a single list or a stream of arrays to a single array. To name a real life example, it is legit to do `reduce(String::concat)` to a stream of strings, giving value semantics to strings, whereas technically, they are just special arrays of characters (implemented as wrapper around an array to enforce immutability). Since this is quiet inefficient, there is the alternative of *mutable reduction*, `collect`; use with `joining()` for `String`s and `toList()` for `List`s

Answer (score 0):

although the solution with plain `for` loop provided by @Holger is good enough, I would like to recommend you try third-party library for this kind of common issues. for example: [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) or JOOL. Here is solution by StreamEx.

```
StreamEx.of(listItems).filter(e -> e.getCounterStatus() == CounterStatus.ACTIVE)
        .scanLeft((a,b) -> { b.setStartCounter(a.getEndCounter()); return b; });
```